# Intercept Print Jobs

Tags: printing

We have some computers on which we charge for printing documents.  When a user prints, I would like to intercept the print job, prompt them for their username / password so I can charge their account, then allow the print job to continue through to the printer.

How can this be accomplished?  Is it possible to write such a utility in .NET?

Answer (score 1):

You really need to look at creating a Port Monitor for this.  Far from simple.  You could look  at [RedMon](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/redmon/).  BTW: Many printer vendors offer solutions to this which use codes that are embedded into the print stream (PCL/PS) and the data is collected and retained on the printer.

For example, Xerox has something called Standard Accounting.  When enabled in the driver it embeds PJL codes like this:

```
@PJL COMMENT OID_ATT_ACCOUNTING_INFORMATION_AVP "XRX_USERID,xxxx";
```

Once the job has been printed the device makes reference to the user, number of pages etc. which can then be reported on.

The problem you will run into when doing this on the workstation / server is that detecting the number of pages printed can be difficult.  If you are trying, for example, to charge by the page you might be able to parse the number of pages from the file, or run through a PCL or PS RIP and determine but if they have a flag for 2up or 4up on the page and that work is done by the printer and not the driver, you will charge the client for 4 pages when they really only printed 1.  That is one of the many pitfalls.

Comment: Can you elaborate at all on these codes?  Or, direct me to a resource that explains them in more detail?

Comment: Added more to my response.  Hope that helps.